# PHP cURL curl_getinfo to make sure postfields are set?

Tags: php, curl

I'm debugging a cURL request on a remote server and I need to inspect that the fields are actually being sent via curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_params );

I've output curl_getinfo($post) but I don't see any indication that the fields are being sent properly.

I can var_dump the parameters as such but I'm still not sure why I'm getting a response that says some fields are invalid:

```
$params = array( 'username' => $un, 'password' => $pw );
$post = curl_init();
$http_build_query = http_build_query( $params );
$curl_params = urldecode( $http_build_query );

  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_params );
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($post, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($post);
```

The response I get is this:

> responseType=exception&errorMessage=1+%3A+Security+error%3A+User+name+or+password+is+invalid&errorCode=1

However, I don't get this security error when I run this on my local machine, only on the development environment.

How can I make sure my request is being passed correctly?

Comment: Why are you using CURLOPT_HTTPGET with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? This is a POST request, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. $post is just a variable name, what makes you think the method is POST?

Comment: You're using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, which is quoted as "The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation."

Comment: Hm, I just replaced CURLOPT_HTTPGET with CURLOPT_POST and got the same result

Comment: Have you tried sending the request to a test URL on your development, just so you can log it? `file_put_contents('postdata.txt', var_export($_POST, true));`

Comment: Ok, i'm a bit new to that - where would postdata.txt be located? In the same directory as it's being called?

Comment: In the same directory as the test URL. It's just a temporary thing.

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm using a CMS with a routing system so I just create a new page and then make that the url for the request but I don't see a file was created.